# css image-replacement when hovering

Tags: css, hover

I have 2 images on my html-page: image2 will replace image1 when hovering.
This is no problem, but the tricky part is that image1 forms a link on it's own and BOTH images should always be displayed on a specified length and width, regardless of the real dimensions of the images.

Now I can manage the hovering-part, the specified set dimensions, the link (href) of image1, but both images will be displayed partly instead of displaying the complete image, but just resized to the specified dimensions.

Can anyone please help?

My html:

```
<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="@Url.Action("TestMethod", "Deal")" ><alt="" class="links" title="plaat1"/></a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My .css:

```
.links { display:block;
        background:url(../../Content/image1.jpg) center top no-repeat;
        height:124px;
        width:186px;
       }

.links:hover { background:url(../../Content/image2.jpg) center top no-repeat;
             }
```

Can anyone please help? Many thanks!

Comment: please setup a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It's pretty messy html... What is <alt="" class="links" title="plaat1"/>? This was supposed to be an "img" tag? Try to put that ".links" clas just inside <a> tag, set sizes for both background images...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use an `IMG` tag if you want to show all the image without being cropped (i.e.: resized). You can do this with the help of a script to set and restore the images when being hovered. Use the `IMG` tag's `SRC` attribute for normal image and the custom `HOVER` attribute for hover image.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .links>img { height:124px; width:186px; }
    </style>
    <script>
      onload = function() {
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('links');
        for (var b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
          var c = a[b].firstElementChild;
          c.setAttribute('img', c.src);
          c.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(ev) {
            ev.target.src = ev.target.attributes['hover'].value;
          }, false);
          c.addEventListener('mouseout', function(ev) {
            ev.target.src = ev.target.attributes['img'].value;
          }, false);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="@Url.Action("TestMethod", "Deal")" class="links" title="plaat1" /><img src="../../Content/image1.jpg" hover="../../Content/image2.jpg" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="@Url.Action("logoff", "Logout")" class="links" title="Log Out" /><img src="../../Content/image2.jpg" hover="../../Content/image3.jpg" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to this html code

```
<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="@Url.Action("TestMethod", "Deal")" class="links" ><alt=""  title="plaat1"/></a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```